# CSS position:fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header with `position:fixed` why it stays on top of other elements and hides them, so I have to add `padding` to `main.` Because the height of `header` varies by content, font-size and padding set by media queries it's not possible to use a fixed value for `padding` as in the snippet. Is there a solution that respects changing heights of `header` without using javascript?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: grey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

main {
  padding-top: 80px; /* bad, because it's fixed */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Example</h1>
</header>
<main>
  <p>Content</p>
</main>
```

Comment: Using 'em' equivalent value of 80px will solve the font-size related issue.

Comment: Yes, but not the other issues. Imagine that you never know the height of `header`..

Comment: I'm going to guess there's no pure css way of doing this because of the nature of `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you can't do it without javascript, but you can fake a fixed header using flexbox and `flex-grow: 1; overflow-y: scroll;` on the main content area.

```css
* {margin:0;}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
main {
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Example</h1>
</header>
<section>
  <main>
    <p>Content</p>
  </main>
</section>
<footer>
  <p>footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can this combined with a sticky footer after `section`? I've also used flexbox for that, but with your changes it won't work anymore. See https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

Comment: @Kiltarc you can use a footer with it and it will behave like the header. updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you can achieve it without the use of Javascript if you want to keep the fixed position. I'd suggest not to use position at all but respect the html hierarchy. And make it "fixed" once scrolling gets it out of the viewport. This is the most typicall approach when you want to have the header visible at all times if height could vary.